# Is there a way to verify that urllib2 responses are complete? I occasionally receive an Httplib.IncompleteRead error.

Tags: python, urllib2, httplib

I have a function which opens a page via `urllib2` to extract some data. It runs fine 80% of the time, but 20% of the time, I'll receive an `IncompleteRead` exception.

#### TraceBack

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 380, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 109, in main
    soups.append(BeautifulSoup(out_queue.get().read()))
  File "c:\python27\lib\socket.py", line 351, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(rbufsize)
  File "c:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 541, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "c:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 601, in _read_chunked
    value.append(self._safe_read(chunk_left))
  File "c:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 649, in _safe_read
    raise IncompleteRead(''.join(s), amt)
httplib.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(958 bytes read, 678 more expected)
```

I'm opening the page via the basic,

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('the_url')
```

and then later in the program converting it to a `BeautifulSoup` object.

Is there a way to catch the problem *when* the initial request is made with `urllib2`? Some way to verify that the data is "whole" *before* I try to do something with it?

Comment: What is `out_queue` here? Are you putting URL responses into a queue? Could those responses share a socket at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read it all at once:

```
try:
    response_data = urllib2.urlopen('the_url').read()
except httplib.IncompleteRead:
    pass # handle the error
```

Comment: I... I don't know why that didn't occur to me.. Thanks!